# Travelling to country with endemic measels - Do I need MMR shot renewed?

Tags: vaccination, travel, endemic, measles

I was born in 1993, received my first MMR vaccine in 1994 and the booster in 1997. I'm about to travel to a country where vaccination rates are lower, and as a result, measels outbreaks still happen regularly. Because I was vaccinated against measels 20 years ago, am I safe from contracting measels in this country (and potentially transmitting it to unvaccinated infants on my return home), or has the vaccine "worn off" by now, making it advisable for me to get a third MMR shot?